Safety pictograms
I am looking for a package that allows to add safety pictograms like those in the following image (I saw that for chemistry pictograms, the ghsystem package existed)


https://ctan.org/pkg/isosafety

In the following code, the option fullpath must be given according to the actual absolute path of the isosafety package in your machine.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fullpath=/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/isosafety]{isosafety}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\noindent
\clist_map_inline:nn {001,002,003,004,005}
  {
    \includegraphics[width=\dimeval{\textwidth/5}]{\Isosign{F#1}}
  }\\
\clist_map_inline:nn {001,002,004,007,008}
  {
    \includegraphics[width=\dimeval{\textwidth/5}]{\Isosign{E#1}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


\Isosign is defines as
\newcommand{\Isosign}[1]{\isosafetypath /isosafety-pdfs/ISO_7010_#1.pdf}

where \isosafetypath is the value of the key fullpath. So \Isosign's duty is just to give the absolute path of the PDF file in the isosafety-pdfs directory.
Note: Currently ISO_7010_E003.pdf, ISO_7010_W012.pdf and ISO_7010_M005.pdf are broken in the isosafety-pdfs directory. This issue has been reported to the package author.

I really cannot understand that package. Just \newcommand{\Isosign}[1]{ISO_7010_#1.pdf} instead of loading the package produces the same output.

Yeah. The package code should be improved.@egreg

Is there a summary of all the pictograms? I found the corresponding pdfs but the list is long and the naming is not very explicit!

@Nicolas The naming is the same as the ISO standard. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_7010
