How can I add danger symbols (fire hazard, danger, ...) into LaTeX?
I need to add some danger symbols into a LaTeX file, but would like to use a package to do so. Pictures would distort the structure. Are there any packages which include that?
Thanks in advance

Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you taken a look at the fontawesome package? It provides several hundred icons.

What do you mean with “distort the structure”? If you want to add ISO signs for dangers, you could check out the isosafety package. But although being a package it would still include pictures in your document. So, I am unsure what your aim is really.

@Mico suggestion if surely a very good answer, but there are also many tikz -based packages providing the symbols. \ If I correctly understand "Pictures would distort the structure", this can be solved by using tikz overlay, or more simply with the \llap and \rlap commands, (and their math versions provided by the \mathtools package). Alternate : \makebox[0pt][<pos>]{....}

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725367/safety-pictograms/725373 could be what you are looking for, as mentioned by Jasper. Or for a more minimalistic version see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372642/looking-for-symbol-fire, that could be a better duplicate.
